# Convert to UNIX timestamp error

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I used this to get the timestamp

```
long epoch = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("09/22/2008 16:33:00").getTime();
```

It returns 989929568.

Then I used online converter to change this number back to standard time,

what I get is

```
05 / 15 / 01 @ 12:26:08pm
```

, not

```
09/22/2008 16:33:00
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change pattern to

```
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

because 22 cannot be month

Comment: I try, but I get 1222115580000, is still not correct.

Comment: that is correct representation of time you entered, why do you think it is incorrect

Comment: I forgot devide by 1000, Thank you